# Serve on multiple ports(http,https) simultaneously using warp framework in Rust

Tags: rust, future, rust-warp

I want to serve multiple connections using [warp](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp) so that I can redirect every http request to https. Here is what I am up to right now.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let http_routes = warp::path("http").map(|| {
        println!("This is http server");
        warp::redirect(Uri::from_static("https://127.0.0.1:2443"))
    });

    let https_routes = warp::any().map(|| {
        println!("This is https server");
        "Hello, World! You are connected through tls connection."
    });

    let _http_warp = warp::serve(http_routes)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 2080)).await;

    let _https_warp = warp::serve(https_routes)
        .tls()
        .cert_path("sec/dmp.cert")
        .key_path("sec/dmp.key")
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 2443)).await;
}
```

This does not work as expected. It only listens on port 2080 and not on 2443

I also tried future::join

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    ----snip----

    let (_http_addr, http_warp) = warp::serve(http_routes)
        .bind_ephemeral(([127, 0, 0, 1], 2080));

    let (_https_addr, https_warp) = warp::serve(https_routes)
        .tls()
        .cert_path("sec/dmp.cert")
        .key_path("sec/dmp.key")
        .bind_ephemeral(([127, 0, 0, 1], 2443));

    future::join(http_warp, https_warp).await?
}
```

This gives error

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be applied to values that implement `std::ops::Try`
  --> src/main.rs:27:5
   |
27 |     future::join(http_wrap, https_wrap).await?
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the `?` operator cannot be applied to type `((), ())`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `((), ())`
   = note: required by `std::ops::Try::into_result`
```

Answer (score 5):

Its completely a simple thing to make this run and that is removing ? suffix from await statement at the end and placing a semicolon.

```
future::join(http_wrap, https_wrap).await? // FROM THIS
future::join(http_wrap, https_wrap).await; // TO THIS
```

And that's it. Now both the futures run simultaneously and thus it listens on both the ports.

Comment: For future readers:: `futures::future::join` function is *not* the same thing as `futures::join!` macro.

Answer (score 3):

here's [kanudo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61424255/8870055) as a complete working example of a tls https redirect in warp

**cert.pem**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**key.rsa**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
warp = { version = "0.2", features = ["tls"] }
futures = "0.3.8"
```

**main.rs**

```
use warp::hyper::Uri;
use warp::Filter;
use futures::future;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let http_routes = warp::path("http").map(|| {
        println!("This is http server");
        warp::redirect(Uri::from_static("https://127.0.0.1:2443"))
    });

    let https_routes = warp::any().map(|| {
        println!("This is https server");
        "Hello, World! You are connected through tls connection."
    });

    let (_http_addr, http_warp) = warp::serve(http_routes)
        .bind_ephemeral(([127, 0, 0, 1], 2080));

    let (_https_addr, https_warp) = warp::serve(https_routes)
        .tls()
        .cert_path("examples/tls/cert.pem")
        .key_path("examples/tls/key.rsa")
        .bind_ephemeral(([127, 0, 0, 1], 2443));

    future::join(http_warp, https_warp).await;
}
```

http://localhost:2080/http redirects to: https://127.0.0.1:2443/

`Hello, World! You are connected through tls connection.`